# Kotlin Generics - It is possible get integer position of an element of whatever type passed like ordinals method does for Enum defined classes?

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, enums, set, ordinal

There's an already built in way that fulfill my request?

I know Set are unordered

I need to do a vector based Set.

I need to know the position of any value of a generic type to place them in the corresponding index of the array, So I can avoid duplications of the elements.

I'm not ordering or defining an order of the Set.
I don't have any operators that missbehave or break any Set Costraint

Please note that I know this implementation is not efficient for any types that seems infinite like Integers.

I need to do it for an educational purpose.

I have already implemented List Ordered and Hash Table based ones.

For now I have this class, that works flawlessy:

```
package ads

class MySet<E : Enum<E>> {

   //More details for clarify
    private val maxSet = 127
    private var myset = arrayOfNulls<Boolean>(maxSet)

   private fun getOrdinal(eelement : E) : Int{
        return eelement.ordinal
   }

   /*
   more set operators that needs of getOrdinal
   */
   fun insert(xelement: E){
        myset[getOrdinal(xelement)] = true
    }

}
```

```
import ads.MySet as RawSet


enum class MyColors{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
    Black,
    Mint;
}

fun main() {

    val myfavc = RawSet<MyColors>()
    val yourfavc = RawSet<MyColors>()

    //Following operations...
    myfavc.insert(MyColors.Red)
    yourfavc.insert(MyColors.Blue)

}
```

I need now to make another class in the same way but working with whatever abstract type already defined in kotlin.

```
package ads

class MySet<T> {

   //More details for clarify
    private val maxSet = 127
    private var myset = arrayOfNulls<Boolean>(maxSet)

   private fun getOrdinal(telement : T) : Int{
        /*
        For any abstract type return the order of any element
        checks if the integer is not greater than maxSet otherwhise it 
        throws an Exception or manages this istance in other way
        */
       
   }

   /*
   more set operators that needs of getOrdinal
   */
   fun insert(xelement: T){
        myset[getOrdinal(xelement)] = true
    }
}
```

```
import ads.MySet as RawSeT
//Istance using Int
fun main() {

    val myfav = RawSet<Int>()
    val yourfav = RawSet<Int>()

    //Following operations...
    myfav.insert(11)
    yourfav.insert(123)

}
```

I guess there's no built-in way to do so in a generic way.
but I'm still learning kotlin, so maybe I'm missing something useful.

I'm not asking to do my paper.

I don't need a full alternative solutions that I should find out by myself but
I'm opened to  read about any tips or resources that can help me to clarify how abstract types works in Kotlin(or Programming Languages) infos like :

- How are ordered.
- If any value of any type can be compared based on their position
  (like c > a for chars).
- Range of values/Max values represented for any "apparently
  infinite" type like Integers.

Thanks you!

P.S. = Please consider that I'm not an english native, be patient!

Comment: Uhm... a `Set` **by definition is unordered**, so your `MySet` should really be named `MyList` or `MyArray` or `MyVector`.

Comment: "Link to already replied answers are accepted." - that's not how SO works. If there is an already-asked (not even _answered_) question that's similar to your own then your question gets closed as a dupe.

Comment: Only types that implement the [Comparable interface](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/) can be compared and ordered. Note that this is totally separate of which data structure you're using to hold these types (like Dai said, a set is unordered by definition).

Comment: @He11Eventh I think you're misunderstanding us. In mathematics and computer-science (and software-engineering), the term "set" is used to refer to a collection of distinct elements/values/objects, without duplicates, which is unordered - i.e. elements do not have an ordinal, index, key, or position inside the set - they either _exist_ in the set or they _don't exist_. Therefore **it is improper** for you name your class `MySet` when it does not behave like a mathematical set.

Comment: I edited the whole question , sorry if it wasn't clear as expected.

Comment: Are you looking for [LinkedHashSet](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-set/)? It preserves order, but it doesn't have indexed access. You could add an indexed accessor to it, but it would have *O(n)* performance instead of *O(1)* because it's a linked implementation.

Comment: In my opinion, there's no need to be so pedantic about the mathematical definition of a Set that you refuse to implement the Set interface on your own ordered collection of distinct elements. I can't think of any use of Set that *requires* the elements to be unordered, so the *interface* definition of Set can be satisfied even if the items are ordered. Just call it an OrderedSet or ArraySet and the intent is clear.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You're right insofar as _you can_, but what you'll end-up with would be something with horrible runtime or space complexity as dictated by the necessary compromises made to implement that. I appreciate I'm being pedantic, but surely you'll agree that _communication is important_, and if we can't agree on semantics then we're doomed.

Comment: How it should work with [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)? What is the _ordinal_ of 3.14, for instance? There must be some predifined subset of instances of `T` to have finite numeration of possibly infinite amount of instances...

Comment: @Dai I don't think the definition of set necessarily means its contents must *not* be ordered. For example, LinkedHashSet describes what it is in addition to being a Set, so there it isn't ambiguous. The problem with making a Set with indices would be the ambiguity about equality between it and other sets, or it and other ordered sets. I think a class like that should be called something like DiscreteList. I think you could make one with either double the memory space as a typical collection, or one with `O(n)` look-up time. These compromises might be acceptable depending on use case

Comment: I don't think is still clear for some of you.
I don't have any intention to define an order to the set.
For whom it says set are unordered in CS it is not right, there's some implemetation of OrderedSet out there used as alternative to maps.
Anyway probably it is the fact that my english writings are not enough to make clear my request.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thanks you. Good point I not even thought about reals numbers. I guess is not possible to do this with Generics , probably I have to manage type by type. 

The enum class implementation in other hands, it works very well. Even with real numbers, it can be defined some reals numbers inside the enum class so it can be managed based on their position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enum`s are implicitly ordered in declaration order and amount of instances of each enum is finite, so they could be ordered globally and their *ordinal* could be represented as `Int`.

`Int`s (as well as `Byte`s and `Char`s) are naturally ordered and have ranges (`Int.MIN_VALUE..Int.MAX_VALUE`, etc.), so each of them could have an *ordinal* represented as `Int` too.

All types implementing `Comparable` interface could be compared in pairs and any subset of their instances could be ordered, but it doesn't mean that each of them have some global `Int` *ordinal* among all possible instances, because set of `Int`s is finite (2^32 items), and set of all unique instances of generic type `T` could be countably infinite (like `BigInteger`) or even uncountable (like `Double`) (see [wiki about cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Finite,_countable_and_uncountable_sets)).

All other types couldn't be even compared in pairs (without respectful `Comparator<T>`).

So you need to manually limit instances of each `T` that are about to be added in your set and either maually order them or provide respectful `Comparator<T>` to construct a `Map<T, Int>` which you'll need to use for subsequent *ordinal* evaluation:

```kotlin
class SetOfSomehowOrderedInstancesOfType<T>(private val order: Map<T, Int>) {
    private val maxSet = order.size
    private var myset = BooleanArray(order.size)

    private fun getOrdinal(eelement: T): Int {
        return order[eelement] ?: throw RuntimeException("Order unknown")
    }

    fun insert(xelement: T) {
        myset[getOrdinal(xelement)] = true
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val myFavouriteRealNumbersInMyFavouriteOrder =
        listOf(99.2123, -2355.12, 1.1, 3.14, 100.0, 123214214215.123331322145)
    val myfavc = SetOfSomehowOrderedInstancesOfType<Double>(myFavouriteRealNumbersInMyFavouriteOrder.mapToIndex())
    myfavc.insert(99.2123) //will be inserted with ordinal = 0

    val myFavouriteRealNumbersInNaturalOrder = myFavouriteRealNumbersInMyFavouriteOrder.sorted()
    val yourfavc = SetOfSomehowOrderedInstancesOfType<Double>(myFavouriteRealNumbersInNaturalOrder.mapToIndex())
    yourfavc.insert(99.2123) //will be inserted with ordinal = 3
}
```

Alternatively you may define `Orderable` and `Ordinator<T>` interfaces (similar to `Comparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>`) and determine *ordinal* using them:

```kotlin
fun interface Ordinator<T> {
    fun getOrderOf(x : T) : Int
}

interface Orderable {
    val order : Int
}

class MySet<T>(private val ordinator: Ordinator<T>? = null) {
    private val maxSet = 127
    private var myset = BooleanArray(maxSet)

    private fun getOrdinal(eelement: T) = when {
        eelement is Orderable -> eelement.order
        ordinator != null -> ordinator.getOrderOf(eelement)
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }

    fun insert(xelement: T) {
        myset[getOrdinal(xelement)] = true
    }
}
```

Also you may define auxilary function, generalizing previous approach:

```
fun <T> ordinatorOf(order: List<T>) = object : Ordinator<T> {
    private val order = order.mapToIndex()
    override fun getOrderOf(x: T) = this.order[x] ?: throw RuntimeException()
}
```

Usage:

```
val stringsOrderedByTheirLength = MySet<String> { it.length }
stringsOrderedByTheirLength.insert("aaa") //will be inserted with ordinal = 3

val myFavouriteRealNumbersInMyFavouriteOrder =
        listOf(99.2123, -2355.12, 1.1, 3.14, 100.0, 123214214215.123331322145)
val myfavc = MySet(ordinatorOf(myFavouriteRealNumbersInMyFavouriteOrder))
myfavc.insert(99.2123) //will be inserted with ordinal = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As somebody pointed out to me that some abstract types representing for an istance Real Numbers can't be done so easily.

The implementation with the enum class works flawlessy but it's been refused from my university professor because I need to use the same syntax for every implementation of the same Data Structure.

Other implementation I have

```
- HashTableSet<T>
- OrderedListSet<T>
```

they ask only for an abstract type that can be whatever type, they will work without problem.

I need to do it the same with the
`ArraySet<E : Enum<E>>`

So if this can't be done easily with Generics, directly...

I'm thinking about mixing them.

Like whatever T type I have
it creates an object called "Domain" so whatever element it insert, before placing them in the array of the set, it place them inside there in a specific order so it simulates what enum it was doing.

I guess that Enumerations can't be defined during the runtime, dinamically.

Then probably I have to define `Domain<T>` as a private class/object(not sure) that :

- Collect the element of the istance of ArraySet(above MySet) inserts with its opeator .insert()
- It orders the element comparing to the ones that are already inside
- Once is ordered delete all the duples
- Re-arrange the whole Boolean Array everytime insert is used based on how Domain grows. (or find out a different algo that partially re-arrange the boolean array)

What do you think?

Advice me more, thanks.